# Xamarin for VS 2015 - Catastrophic failure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, downgrade

Few hours ago I updated my Xamarin version to the latest one 4.7.10
Everything was fine during the update process and it finished without any errors.
After this when I opened one of my projects which is Xamarin.Forms project and I tried to open any .xaml file I was getting this strange error:

[image]

Whatever I tried there was no success at all with this error. I was forced to downgrade Xamarin version to the previous one and everything now is OK.
Is there anybody who has faced the same error now or before and how did you managed to cope with this bug. And how it is possible released production 'better' version to have such a major bug...

Comment: I have the same problem, and I'm glad to see its not just me.  It was driving me crazy!  I will now downgrade my Xamarin version.  How could they let such a blatant and crippling error make it into a "stable" release?!  This should have been detected before the alpha stage!

Comment: You are damn right, I don't know how and why they let this stupid error but it pissed me off. Downgrading is the only solution for now...

Comment: I'm providing one more solution from Xamarin forums. You can check it here: [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/301280/#Comment_301280)

Comment: FYI: I also found the issue does not occur in VS 2017.  Originally I was working in VS 2015

Answer (score 2):

I got this error too when trying to open a XAML file in Visual Studio 2015. The [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/301280/#Comment_301280) Kris provided in the comments solved it for me. Right click on the XAML file and select "Open With..." followed by "Automatic Editor Selector (XML)". Note that this will open the XAML file without the designer but you can open the Xamarin.Forms Previewer window by going to View > Other Windows > Xamarin.Forms Previewer. More information about the previewer can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/).

Answer (score 1):

I am becoming more and more convinced that really Xamarin is the Catastrophic Failure here.

Comment: Bhaahahhahahaha. Really.